# Google Schema.org Math solvers structured data for multiple fields

Tags: math, schema.org, json-ld, google-schemas

Trying to setup schema markup for a simple math solver action with two fields. Let's say addition.

`1+1=2`

Here is Google's [doc](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/math-solvers#example) and example:

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": ["MathSolver", "LearningResource"],
  "name": "An awesome math solver",
  "url": "https://www.mathdomain.com/",
  "usageInfo": "https://www.mathdomain.com/privacy",
  "inLanguage": "en",
  "potentialAction": [{
    "@type": "SolveMathAction",
    "target": "https://mathdomain.com/solve?q={math_expression_string}",
    "mathExpression-input": "required name=math_expression_string",
    "eduQuestionType": ["Polynomial Equation","Derivative"]
   }],
  "learningResourceType": "Math solver"
}
```

How do we add multiple variables for two numbers?

```
return {
    '@context': 'https://schema.org',
    '@type': ['MathSolver', 'LearningResource'],
    ...
    potentialAction: [
        {
            '@type': 'SolveMathAction',
            target: `domain.com/?num1={num1}&num2={num2}`,
            'mathExpression-input': 'required name=num1 name=num2',
            eduQuestionType: ['addition', 'sum']
        },
    ],
    learningResourceType: 'Math solver'
};
```

[Schema.org](https://schema.org/MathSolver) says about `mathExpression` (note: `mathExpression-input` doesnt seem to exist) but does fall under `Thing > Intangible  EntryPoint`

> A mathematical expression (e.g. 'x^2-3x=0') that may be solved for > a specific variable, simplified, or transformed. This can take many > formats, e.g. LaTeX, Ascii-Math, or math as you would write with a > keyboard.

But can this be setup for URL params to accept [multiple](https://schema.org/docs/actions.html#part-4) fields within the `mathExpression-input` instead of a single math expression?